# Wordpress permalink not working on aws

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, permalinks, httpd.conf

I have spent 4-5 hours to sort it out but not able to solve it.

I have setup my wordpress website on AWS.Everything is working file except the permalinks of wordpress.

When permalinks are set to default pages/posts are working but not working with "%post-name%".

I have tried almost all the things by searching over google but no success.

I saw so many solutions all related to **httpd.conf** file but on my root there is no file httpd.conf neither no directory of http.

I changed the following code in **apache.conf** file but still not working

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restarted apache again and again but no luck.

Please help me guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've just managed to fix this error. **Make sure you restart Apache service after making the httpd.conf change!**

---

Documentation here has a checklist of all the changes you need to get wordpress working correclty on AWS - including getting permissions correct: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

The bit you need to fix for permalinks is tp **update the httpd.conf file**

**(1) Location: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

**(2) Find the section that starts with** `<Directory "/var/www/html">`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

Change the **AllowOverride None** line in the above section to read **AllowOverride All**

**Note**
There are multiple AllowOverride lines in this file; be sure you change the line in the  section.

```
AllowOverride All
```

**(3) Restart the Apache service**

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have much experience using aws, then i guess its because you have not granted enough permissions to your apache. If you are unware of how to grant permissions to your apache, you can use this command in your console

```
sudo CHOWN -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Once done try going to your settings page and saving the new settings.

Answer (score 0):

It require to change the FollowSymLinks to ALL

Follow below steps:

Step 1: Run below command on terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Step 2: search for

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

change None to All as displayed below:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Step 3: save the file by pressing Ctrl+X, then, press Y , hit Enter.

Step 4: restart apache with below command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**That's it. thank you**

if issue still persist try below command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then below command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```